# web.py sessions note remembered when running the app under mod_wsgi

Tags: python, session, wsgi, web.py

For some reason it seems like web.py isn't capable of remembering my sessions. It works fine with the built-in webserver, but when I use my application with WSGI, sessions aren't remembered.

I checked the diskstore session folder and there are files being created. It just seems it doesn't 'remember' the sessions.

I have this in my code:

```
app = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=False)
application = app.wsgifunc()
curdir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
session = web.session.Session(
    app, web.session.DiskStore(os.path.join(curdir, 'sessions')), 
    { 'name': None, 'uid': 0, 'logged_in': False, 
      'username': None, 'password': None})
```

When I execute this part of login it redirects fine to `/account` on the built-in webserver (my post method checks the login and then sets logged_in to `True`), but in wsgi it just returns the loginscreen again:

```
def GET(self):
    if session.logged_in != True:
        return self.getLoginScreen()
    else:
        raise web.seeother('/account')
```

Running WSGI with Apache2 on Ubuntu 12.04. My apache2 error log is empty.

Comment: Are you sure the server-process has write access to the sessions directory?

Comment: I think so, the sessions are getting created in the sessions folder.